# Get thumbnail of image with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, imageview

I am displaying rows from the DB using ListView. I am displaying full resolution images in my rows, which is causing my phone to lag. How can I display thumbnails instead.

```
public void getListFromDb(){
    Cursor res = myDb.ViewAll();
    startManagingCursor(res);


    //Map cursor from db to viewFields
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL_2, DatabaseHelper.COL_3, DatabaseHelper.COL_4, DatabaseHelper.COL_5, DatabaseHelper.COL_6};
    int[] toViewIDS = new int[]{R.id.viewName, R.id.viewAddress, R.id.viewPostcode, R.id.viewType, R.id.imageView};

    //Create SimpleCursorAdaptor with null cursor
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_layout, null, fromFieldNames, toViewIDS, 0);
    // Set adaptor for listView
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdaptor);

    new AsyncTask<SimpleCursorAdapter, Void, Cursor>() {
        private SimpleCursorAdapter mSimpleCursorAdapter;
        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(SimpleCursorAdapter... params) {
            // Save cursorAdapter to use in postExecute
            this.mSimpleCursorAdapter = params[0];
            // Load cursor on background thread with search function
               return myDb.ViewAll();
            }
        }
```

I am retrieving the Real path for the image from the DB

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Read google's documentation, with sample code which allows you to downscale images to the size you want.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html